# editing text file using awk and making new one

Tags: bash, awk

I have text file like small example:

```
ENSG00000001036 ENST00000002165 6   143832827   143832772
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24766730;24746130;24768628;24742394;24759703    24766662;24745781;24768545;24742293;24759594
ENSG00000004139 ENST00000003834 17      
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1   24740215;24727946   24740164;24727857
```

I want to edit the file and make a new file. in fact the fist line is fine and other lines should look like this one. in the 3rd line I do not have fields 4 and 5 so I will remove such lines completely. but there are some lines like lines 3 and 4 in the example. in such lines 4 and 5 are `;` separated. I want to divide these lines into more than one depending the number of `;` separated parts. for instance the 2nd line will be converted into 5 lines and line 4 will be divided into 2 lines. the new lines would have the same 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns but the difference is in the columns 4 and 5. here is 2 new resulting lines from the 4th line.

```
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1   24740215    24740164
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1   24727946    24727857
```

as it is shown in the above 2 lines, the 1st column of the field number 4 and 5 would be the fields number 4 and 5 in the 1st new line and the 2nd column of the field number 4 and 5 would be the fields number 4 and 5 in the 2nd new line. so the result of the small example would look like this:

```
ENSG00000001036 ENST00000002165 6   143832827   143832772
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24766730    24766662
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24746130    24745781
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24768628    24768545
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24742394    24742293
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1   24759703    24759594
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1   24740215    24740164
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1   24727946    24727857
```

I wrote a small code using `awk`:

```
awk -F";" '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5}' coord.txt > new.txt.
```

but actually I do not now how to apply 2 conditions that I mentioned (splitting lines and deleting incomplete lines). do you know how to do that?

Comment: NF holds the number of fields, you could use this to determine how many ; were in the line

Comment: Setting the field delimiter to semicolon is the wrong approach, since you want to split the other fields on spaces. This is an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk` command with `split` on fourth and fifth field on `semi-colon`:

```
awk 'NF==5{n=split($4, a, /;/); split($5, b, /;/);
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, $2, $3, a[i], b[i]}' file

ENSG00000001036 ENST00000002165 6 143832827 143832772
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1 24766730 24766662
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1 24746130 24745781
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1 24768628 24768545
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1 24742394 24742293
ENSG00000001461 ENST00000003912 1 24759703 24759594
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1 24740215 24740164
ENSG00000001460 ENST00000003583 1 24727946 24727857
```

Comment: I was working on something along these lines but yours is shorter and sweeter than mine. +1, cheers.